# path error in pkgdown article with multiple bibliographies

Tags: r, pkgdown

I have a vignette of a R-package with multiple bibliographies (MB), using a [lua filter](https://github.com/pandoc/lua-filters/tree/master/multiple-bibliographies). When I try to turn the vignette with MB into a pkgdown article I got an error for the .lua and .bib files, that do not appeared with the vignette.

```
pkgdown::build_article("index", pkg = ".", data = list(), lazy = FALSE,
  quiet = FALSE) # build index.Rmd vignette (located in vignettes folder) as article

openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory
```

WORKAROUND: If I use the whole path of files, problem disappears: `/home/user..`

NOTE: For pandoc >2.11 each bibliography accepts only one .bib

Vignette (index.Rmd) with MB, example yaml section:

```
pkgdown:
  as_is: true
output:
  rmarkdown::html_vignette:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 1
    number_sections: true
    pandoc_args: --lua-filter=multiple-bibliographies.lua

bibliography_normal: [allrefs.bib]
bibliography_software: [packages.bib, Rrefs.bib]
bibliography_docs: [docPackages.bib]
```

For testing purposes you will need a package DESCRIPTION file, one is available in [link](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html). See also [link](http://tinyheero.github.io/jekyll/update/2015/07/26/making-your-first-R-package.html) about creating a package. In order to create a vignette, install R-Studio, go to File, new file, R-markdown, From Template, Package Vignette. Important: Check the lua filter link also to learn what is MB in this Post. To add cites use `[@R-plyr]` in body, or use this in yaml section:

```
nocite: |
   @R-plyr
```

In order to create .bib files use:

```
knitr::write_bib(c("devtools","plyr","dplyr"), 'packages.bib')
```

Notes: Requires pandoc > 2

Comment: Can you give us your bib-file or a working example which reproduces your error?

Comment: Hi @j-f, see edits please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved adding files to yaml:

```
resource_files:
  - multiple-bibliographies.lua
  - allrefs.bib
```